# rtl8188eus wireless adapter my kali linux with kernel version 5.3.0 now the problem is the monitor mode & packet injection not working

Tags: linux, kali-linux, drivers

when I try to install the driver from the manufacture it shows me that's error
[image]

Comment: Maybe try [github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus).

Comment: still not working